# how to call a function on alert something on cursor enter to the input text box by using TAB?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i just wants to call a function when my cursor on a form move to the input text box by pressing TAB.also when i click it->i just wants to show a message.mu html code-->

```
<input onclick="$('#limitDayExitWarning').show(),$('#limitDayExitWarning').html('Plase insert a value [1|2].Means, how many day of this batch class will be held in one Week')" class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="number" placeholder="Day In A Week*" id="idayInAWeek" name="dayInAWeek" autocomplete="off">
  <label id="limitDayExitWarning" style="display: none;color: red;"></label>
```

the level is show/apper html on click->means when cursor move by using mouse.but when i move cursor from other field to my desire field by using Tabs my desire level is not displaying.

I also tried `OnFocus`:

```
<input onfocus="$('#limitDayExitWarning').show(),$('#limitDayExitWa‌​rning').html('Plase insert a value [1|2].Means, how many day of this batch class will be held in one Week')" onclick="$('#limitDayExitWarning').show(),$('#limitDayExitWa‌​rning').html('Plase insert a value [1|2].Means, how many day of this batch class will be held in one Week')"
class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="number" placeholder="Day In A Week*" id="idayInAWeek" name="dayInAWeek" autocomplete="off">
<label id="limitDayExitWarning" style="display: none;color: red;"></label>
```

Comment: Have you looked into `OnFocus`? ► [https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-onfocus](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-onfocus)

Comment: yes i tried it ......

Comment: Can you add your code you tried with it to see why it might not work?

Comment: <input onfocus="$('#limitDayExitWarning').show(),$('#limitDayExitWarning').html('Plase insert a value [1|2].Means, how many day of this batch class will be held in one Week')" onclick="$('#limitDayExitWarning').show(),$('#limitDayExitWarning').html('Plase insert a value [1|2].Means, how many day of this batch class will be held in one Week')" class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="number" placeholder="Day In A Week*" id="idayInAWeek" name="dayInAWeek" autocomplete="off">
      <label id="limitDayExitWarning" style="display: none;color: red;"></label>

Answer (score 0):

Use the `focus` event to do something when the user tabs, clicks or otherwise moves into the `<input>`. Use `blur` to do something when they leave:

```
<input type="number" id="idayInAWeek" name="dayInAWeek">
<label id="limitDayExitWarning">blah blah</label>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#idayInAWeek').
            on('focus', function() { $('#limitDayExitWarning').show(); }).
            on('blur', function() { $('#limitDayExitWarning').hide(); });
    });
</script>
```